# 'if i, j in zip(range...)' gives syntax error in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move a sprite depending on a direction entered in a different section of code, but I am getting a syntax error.

```
def move(self, direction):
    if i, j in zip(range(4),[[0,-1],[0,1],[-1,0],[1,0]]):
        if direction == i:
            Character.x+= j[0]
            Character.y += j[1]
```

The red highlighting of the error is over the comma between i and j. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Did you want a `for` loop? That `if` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a `for` loop, as shown in Simon's answer, but there's a much simpler way that doesn't use loops or `zip`.

```
def move(self, direction):
    steps = [[0,-1], [0,1], [-1,0], [1,0]]
    j = steps[direction]
    Character.x += j[0]
    Character.y += j[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write `for` not `if`:

```
for i, j in zip(range(4),[[0,-1],[0,1],[-1,0],[1,0]]):
```

Comment: Perhaps, but a loop isn't required for this simple task.

Comment: Yes, maybe his snippet is not the complete code. Anyways this works and is what OP wanted the code to do.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this is what OP wanted his code to do as this code does not make much sense.

Comment: His code is a little strange, but the task description is pretty clear. Your `for` loop will work, but it's a bit pointless, since we can just index directly into `[[0,-1],[0,1],[-1,0],[1,0]]`.